# aggregate with multiple functions in r

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a simple dataframe, and want to aggregate on both mean and count of each.

I have three steps:

```
aggregate(x$value1,list(x$col1),mean)
aggregate(x$value1,list(x$col1),nrow)
merge(d1,d2,by='Group.1')
colnames(m)=c('col1','mean','count')
```

I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this in R.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `aggregate(value1 ~ col1, x, function(p) c(mean(p), length(p)))`

Comment: I would suggest using the `dplyr` package. You could do : `x %>% group_by(col1) %>% summarise(mean=mean(value1),count=n())`

Comment: thanks, I knew it was there!! Don't code 10hours straight without caffeine